# Show that for any $r>0$ and $z \in \mathbb{C}$ we have that $B_r(z)\subset S_r(z)$

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

> Show that for any $r>0$ and $z \in \mathbb{C}$ we have that
>   $B_r(z)\subset S_r(z)$

In other words, that any Ball of radius $r>0$ centred at $z \in \mathbb{C}$ is a subset of the square $S_r(z)$ centred at $z$, defined by $$S_r(z) = [w \in \mathbb{C} : Re(w-z), Im(w-z) \in (-r,r)]$$By visualising or by sketching a picture, this statement seems to be trivially true. However I would like to prove it.

I would like to show that for any  $w \in B_r(z)$ we have that $$w \in B_r(z)\Rightarrow w \in S_r(z)$$ By definition of the Ball I can say that $$B_r(z) = [w \in \mathbb{C} : |w-z|<r]$$ However I am unsure how to piece these definitions together to efficiently prove the statement. Any ideas are appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I would probably go for a proof by contraposition. Assume that you have a point outside of the square and show that then it must also be outside of the circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $|\operatorname{re} w| \le |w|$ and $|\operatorname{im} w| \le |w|$.

If $w \in B_r(z)$ then $|w-z| < r$. Then
$|\operatorname{re} (w-z)| \le |w-z|< r$  and similarly for $\operatorname{im}$.
hence $w \in S_r(z)$.